# Xamarin Android jQuery AJAX doesn't work in Release Mode

Tags: jquery, ajax, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-webview

I have an app for Android in Xamarin. I have a HTML page in my WebView and I use AJAX for requests. In debug mode it works perfect but in release mode it gives error.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'http://****.com',
   data: data,
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data, status) {
      alert('success')
   },
   error: function(xmlRequest) {
      alert('error')
   }
});
```

Here is my webview code:

```
 WebView app_view = null;
 WebSettings app_web_settings = null;


protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
   SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

   app_view = FindViewById(Resource.Id.webViewApp) as WebView;
   app_web_settings = app_view.Settings;
   app_web_settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
   app_web_settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
   app_web_settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
   app_web_settings.DatabaseEnabled = true;
   app_web_settings.SetRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.High);
   app_view.SetLayerType(LayerType.Hardware, null);
   my_web_client = new MyWebViewClient(this);
   web_client = new WebChromeClient();
   app_view.SetWebViewClient(my_web_client);
   app_view.SetWebChromeClient(web_client);

  string app_url = "file:///android_asset/app_pages/home.html";
  app_view.LoadUrl(app_url);
  app_view.AddJavascriptInterface(new Foo(this), "foo");
}
```

Comment: And your WebView code looks like what? In Release mode, what kind of linking do you have enabled?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I edit and add my webview code. In Android Options linking "Sdk Assemblies Only" selected

Comment: Also, what does "in release mode it gives error." mean? What error?

Comment: @Cheesebaron ajax returns error when release mode. But in debug mode I can send and get parameter from services. Is that relevant with "http" or "https"?

Comment: Check the xmlRequest and see what the exact reason for the failure is.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my ajax request and I use jsonp method. It works successfull in release mode.

```
 $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'http://****.com',
        data: data,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data, status) {
          alert('success')
        },
        error: function(xmlRequest) {
          alert('error')
        }
      });
```

Comment: I did as you did but I still have the problem when I use https

I found during the research that there are restrictions or problems in connecting to my services through shared hosting Is that true or not?

Comment: @AsmaaMohamed, in this example, I also developed the backend. I have given the necessary permissions for communication. I had not tried to connect to another hosting.

Comment: [According to this,](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/) sites should provide JSONP services.

Comment: Thank you for reply , I found the solution, which is to change my website certificate to trusted certificate