# why call ajax webservice with https not working in android xamarin webview

Tags: c#, ajax, ssl, https, xamarin.android

web service work fine in browser and when call in c#
but when call using ajax not work

call using ajax work when http without ssl
but when add ssl certificate to my website , ajax not work

code ajax

```
     $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: 'https://example.com/WebService/About/1?lang=en',
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                document.getElementById("net").textContent = "Network Error";

            },
            success: function (response, $Id) {
                document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = response.Details.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
            }
        });
```

code web service

```
    public JsonResult About(string lang, int Id)
    {
        var data = db.AboutUs.ToList().Where(x => x.Id == Id).Select(m => new { m.Id, Details = lang == "ar" ? m.Text : m.TextEn }).FirstOrDefault();
        var jsonResult = Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return jsonResult;
    }
```

and added code in server web config

web.config

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

i can not find where problem in my code
i use interserver.net web hosting

plz help me

Comment: Here is a working sample : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55038009/xamarin-android-jquery-ajax-doesnt-work-in-release-mode . Try to change the ajax request and use jsonp instead .

Comment: I found during the research that there are restrictions or problems in connecting to my services through shared hosting 

Is that true or not? @ColeX - MSFT

Comment: I did like this link but I still have the problem when I use https

Comment: I'm not sure, but If the request works in browser it should also work in xamarin webview .

Comment: Thank you for reply , I found the solution, which is to change my website certificate to trusted certificate 
@ColeX-MSFT